# Can you end a MATLAB program from inside a GUI?

Tags: matlab

I have a program that I am running that uses video and the only way to stop it(right now) once it starts is to press Ctl+C.

My file contains a GUI which displays the live video feed and then a filtered version of it in the same GUI.  I can add a close button to the gui with:

"uicontrol('String', 'Close', 'Callback', 'close(gcf)');"

The problem is that this just closes that window...which pops right back up since the code is endlessly looping.

Is there a way to set up the close button such that, when pressed, it not only closes the GUI but also ends the program?

Comment: How is your video being played? Are you animating it yourself? If so, are you using a timer or are you looping with `pause` statements?

Comment: I figured out a way to do it....As I said I have an endless loop.  I just changed the endless loop so that instead of just triggering off nothing(aka just going from 1:inf), I made it trigger off a variable I called CL(for close)(eg. While (Close ~= 1)) which I set inside that function:  uicontrol('String', 'Close', 'Callback', 'CL = 1;');

Answer (score 0):

> I figured out a way to do it....As I said I have an endless loop. I just changed the endless loop so that instead of just triggering off nothing(aka just going from 1:inf), I made it trigger off a variable I called CL(for close)(eg. While (Close ~= 1)) which I set inside that function: uicontrol('String', 'Close', 'Callback', 'CL = 1;'); – Bryan Oct 29 '10 at 22:39

I'm pretty sure that the way you did it is the only nice way of doing it. `CTRL-C` is also kind of a hack on Windows as it does not handle signals the way UNIX does.